# Coexisting UWP Solution and Windows 8.1 Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1, uwp

I am trying to co-exist UWP solution and Windows 8.1 solution. Basically, I have 2 separate solutions / projects but using the same set of files (backwards compatible).

I am having problem with the project.json. Whenever I try to compile the Windows 8.1 solution, it always gives me this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Your project is not referencing the ".NETCore,Version=v4.5.1"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETCore,Version=v4.5.1" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.  Dovetail.POS.EventLog

I read that project.json is specifically for Windows UWP project. However, since I am compiling Windows 8.1 project, isn't it supposed to not care about the project.json?

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First I created a seperate solution for the UWP project.

Then removed the UWP from the old solution.

Then removed the project.json file from the Windows 8.1 application. (temporary file in the root of your project)

Restarted Visual Studio.

And it works again.